# XAML errors using an assembly name different from the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a project with the Namespace: `Product.Main` and the Assembly: `Product`

In XAML, I have: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Product.Main"`

Everything works fine when both Namespace and Assembly are the same.  When they are different, and I go to the XAML designer, everytime I call `local:` I get an error:

`The name "ContentView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Product.Main".`

and I get `Invalid Markup` in designer when I try to view a control using `local`.  I use `local` many times, so my Error list lists an error for every time I use it.  Everything builds and runs successfully, it is just annoying that I can't view my controls in designer and all the errors that are listed every time I build.

Is there a way to circumvent these errors and get designer to work when I use an Assembly name that is different than the namespace?  I don't want my output to be `Product.Main.exe`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: not to sound cliche, have you tried to clean your solution or try restarting VS or machine?  I have had a similar problem before.

Comment: Not sure if I should delete the question; if you add this as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.  Not sure why restarting VS worked, but it did. Wouldn't mind it if a reader could attach more meaning to why it behaves this way! Thanks @DROPtableusers.

Comment: I added it as an answer, thanks for marking it.  Glad it solved your problem, I am not sure at all why this happens just some weird bug I guess.  For reference I am running 32 bit Windows 7 with VS 2012. @NETscape

Comment: I would also leave the question up, seems as though this might be a recurring issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment earlier.

> Not to sound cliche, have you tried to clean your solution or try
>   restarting VS or machine? I have had a similar problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this since your assembly does not match your namespace.

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Product.Main;assembly=Product"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've tried this, it says there is no such assembly... even after rebuilding

Comment: @NETscape Are you using resharper? You may want to look into clearing its caches and restarting Visual Studio. You are getting false errors from something so I would start looking at addons.